# How do I search nested divs using regex for class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to search for nested divs like these in my DOM

```
 <div class="two-columns some-other-class">
      <div class="two-columns some-other-class">
      </div>
 </div>
```

I tried to search nested divs like this

```
$("div[class$='columns'] div[class$='columns']")
```

but it's not working :(

Comment: I'd reccomend not using regex for this. See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Sandeep: Never change the question when people have answered it, instead make a EDIT

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Karna .... I'm new to this space and didn't know this part. Will take care next time.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$("div[class*='columns'] div[class*='columns']")
```

**Edit:**

If you want that *exact* functionality you might want to extend the jQuery selector engine:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    classEndsWith: function(e, i, meta) {
        var found = false
        var classes = e.className.toLowerCase().split(' ');
        var suffix = meta[3].toLowerCase();
        $.each(classes, function(i, c) {
            // Check if className ends with value in suffix
            if (c.indexOf(suffix, c.length - suffix.length) !== -1) {
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return found;
    }
});

var element = $('div:classEndsWith(columns) div:classEndsWith(columns)');
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2b37/5/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[class$='columns'] div[class$='columns']")
```

Is working. Check the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCLPt/)

Comment: The question changed so this will not work with the new parameters.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Thanks for bringing it to notice!

Comment: Apologies for changing the question, I didn't know how to make edit.